# necesito buscar elementos de una funcion python y mostrarlos en otra funcion llamada buscar

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

soy nuevo en la programación en python y en la empresa donde trabajo me mandaron a buscar elementos que están en una lista en la función **def nombres()** y extraerlos para mostrarlos en una función **def buscar()**

así es el menú de opciones

```
def menu():
print ("\n")
print ("______________menu____________________")
print ("Selecciona una opcion")
print ("\t1 - insertar nombres")
print ("\t2 - buscar nombres")
print ("cualquier otra es para salir")

while True:
menu()
opcion=input("inserta una opcion ")
if opcion == 1:
    nombres()
elif opcion == 2:
    buscar()
else:
    sys.exit(1)
```

básicamente los valores almacenados en las variables de la función **nombres()** llamarlos en la función **buscar**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la programación orientada a objetos lo que se usa son `return` para devolver el valor de una función a otra. Pero con tu código actual ya que debes elegir una opción u otra, lo más sensato sería usar una clase (supongo, porque no vemos el código de la funcion nombres).

```
class Programa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombres = [] # O carga aqui la base de datos donde tengas los nombres.

    def menu(self):
        print("\n")
        print("______________menu____________________")
        print("Selecciona una opcion")
        print("\t1 - insertar nombres")
        print("\t2 - buscar nombres")
        print("cualquier otra es para salir")

        while True:.
            menu()
            opcion=input("inserta una opcion ")
            if opcion == 1:
                self.añadir_nombres()
            elif opcion == 2:
                self.buscar()
            else:
                sys.exit(1)

    def añadir_nombres(self):
        nuevo_nombre = input("Añadir nombre: ")
        self.nombres.append(nuevo_nombre)
        # NOTA: Añadelo también a la base de datos que useis.
        print("Nombre añadido.")

    def buscar(self):
        nombre_a_buscar = input("¿Cual busco?: ")
        if nombre_a_buscar in self.nombres:
            print("No está en la lista.")
        else:
            print("Sí está en la lista.)"

Programa() # Ejecutamos la clase.
```

Te recomiendo mirar algún tutorial sobre `clases` en python hasta que entiendas el código que acabo de escribir.